# Query from a subset

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I have a table with several attributes like this:

```
id  id2  attribute
--------------------------------
 1  100  blue 
 2  100  red
 3  100  green
 4  100  white
 5  102  blue
 6  102  green
 7  102  red
 8  103  red
 9  103  blue
10  103  white
11  104  red
12  104  black
13  104  green
14  104  orange
15  105  red
16  105  blue
17  105  green
```

I want to know:
what are the top attributes for the entries that have 'blue'?
what are the top attributes for the entries that have 'blue' and 'red'?

For the second query the results should be:

```
attribute   count1
--------------------
green       3
white       2
```

I can build the query dynamically. I have this working, using this approach:

```
SELECT
  mytable.attribute,
  count(mytable.id) as count1
FROM
    mytable,
    (SELECT
     id
    FROM
     mytable
    WHERE
     attribute in ('blue', 'red')
    GROUP BY
     id2
    HAVING
     count(distinct attribute) = 2) as t
WHERE
 mytable.id = t.id
and
 attribute NOT IN ('blue', 'red')
GROUP BY
 mytable.attribute
ORDER BY
 count1 desc
```

The problem is that if the inner query has a lot of entries the while process takes too long. Can anyone suggest a way to improve this?

Comment: . . The top attribute for entities that have "blue" is "blue", unless you allow duplicates (which the sample data does not have).  Hence, I don't understand the question.  Can you clarify it?

Comment: I've just updated the results with an example. I want the top counts of everything that is not blue, if the query is blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel. Try this:

```
select attribute, count(1) as count1
from mytable
where id2 in (
    select distinct t.id2
    from mytable t
    join mytable t1 on (t1.id2 = t.id2 and t1.attribute = 'red')
    where t.attribute = 'blue')
and attribute not in ('blue', 'red')
group by attribute
order by count1 desc;
```

Of course you will need some indexes. These could be enough:

```
1 > id2, attribute
2 > attribute, id2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for "blue":

```
select t.attribute, count(*)
from mytable t
where exists (select 1
              from mytable tblue
              where tblue.attribute = 'blue' and
                    tblue.id2 = t.id2
             ) and
      t.attribute <> 'blue'
group by t.attribute
order by count(*) desc;
```

For "blue" and "red", you could just add another `exists` clause.

For performance, create an index on `mytable(id2, attribute)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but this query actually is 5x slower than the original. I've tested it in the real database. I have (attribute, id2) (id2,attribute) and (id2) indexes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MiguelE . . . That is unexpected.  I would expect the `exists` to be much faster than the `group by`.  Can you put `explain` in front of this query and see if it is using the appropriate index for the subquery?  Maybe with three indexes, MySQL is getting confused.

Comment: the explain shows that the (id2, attribute) index is being used. This table has about 14 million rows. I've asked for help in the DBAdministrators too and there I got a suggestion with a minor improvement: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63868/nested-query-efficiency-in-mysql#63872 . Not enough. I'll have to review my data structure if I can't get this under 1 second.

Comment: @MiguelE . . . How selective is "blue"?  That is, what proportion of the ids match these conditions?

Comment: I'll have to handle anything. It can return 50K rows or more, but I just need the top 100. I've tried with a LIMIT clause, but the improvement is not much, maybe 10% on the rendering side.

Comment: If you can put in a limit, can you ask another question?  Please explain how the limit would be used.  There may be other approaches for that case.